# Are there some examples of Kac-Moody groups which are not reductive?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Are there some examples of Kac-Moody groups which are not reductive? Thank you very much.

Comment: What does it mean for a Kac-Moody group to be reductive?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I would like to know some concrete examples.

Comment: That's not an answer to my question. What does it mean for a Kac-Moody group to be reductive?